# Getting error "Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist." when adding web part

Tags: web-part, visual-studio, visual-web-part

I have created a web part in visual studio, it deploys fine, but when I try to add it to a page I get the following error:

> Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))

I read that this could happen due to disposing of objects too soon, so I changed

```
using (SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site)
```

to this

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
```

but it didn't fix anything.  Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

UPDATE:

I'm not using SPWeb but I use the SPSite object here:

```
using (FullTextSqlQuery fullTextSqlQuery = new FullTextSqlQuery(site))
```

Comment: Can you post your SPWeb code as well?

Comment: I'm not using SPWeb.  I went ahead and posted the code that is using the SPSite object though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After correcting your code, please make sure that your web part is the only one on the page.  It may be that other custom web parts are using the uncorrected code and thus disposing of the SPSite object before your web part can access it.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code snippet would produce exactly the error message you saw, the second *should* fix it.

Try an IISReset, just to be absolutely sure your latest code is being loaded?

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't dispose SPContext.Current.Site at all.

Comment: I did an IIS reset, and I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: Is this the only custom web part on that page?  use the ?contents=1 url trick to make sure

Comment: No it's not the only one.  I only get the error when I try to add this web part though.

Comment: Ooohhh are you thinking it might be caused by another web part disposing incorrectly?

Comment: @Dave, that was it.  If you post that as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SPContext.Current.Site` to access the current site. Do not create any new SPSite object can be taxing on resources, you can use the current site from the SPContext.